# my 'style.css' file doesn't work when i put a class attribute in form tag

Tags: html, css

what's wrong with this code?
I want to give my form tag a class attribute and design it but it doesn't work. when i delete class attribute, it works

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
form .register {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 400px auto 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sign Up!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    
<form action="/sign_up" method="POST" class="register">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" class="btn">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `form .register` is not the proper selector for *"form with class 'register'"*. The space between them denotes "descendant of". Removing the space refers to an element that satisfies both selectors, `form` and `.register, and is likely what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `form` and `.register` in your CSS selector.

Currently it's selecting all children of a `form` element that have the class `register`. Removing the space will select `form` elements that themselves have the class `register`.

```
form.register {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 400px auto 0;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unwanted space between `form` and `.register`. It should be `form.register`.

In CSS, whitespace between two selectors indicates a "descendant-of" rule, so `form .register` selects any element with `class="register"` that is a descendant-of any `<form>` elemenets, but not `<form class="register">`.

Answer (score 0):

You have used selectors wrongly, space should not be there between **form** and **.register** class.

Ex. 
**form .register** -> It selects all elements inside form tag (Space is there between form tag register class)

**form.register** -> It will select form tag with class register (as your expected)

Answer (score 0):

use form.register instead of form .register. The unwanted space is the problem. You can also use .register if you have no other stuff with class register.